# deployed streamlit to share with others. It is giving error with sklearn model

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I have [github](https://github.com/Datatashi/instantloan) ready with all files. I am trying to deploy the app on streamlit to share with others. However, I am getting errors like the following.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJgQX.jpg)

Comment: You didn't add `requirements.txt` file, add all required packages.

Comment: How to add requirements.txt. I am a novice here.